# CMake macro return from middle of the flow?

Tags: cmake

Can I return from the middle of a CMake `macro`? A use case I have in mind is below.

```
macro (my_macro a b c)
    if (NOT USE_${a})
         # I WANT TO RETURN FROM HERE.
    endif ()
    if (NOT USE_${b})
         # I WANT TO RETURN FROM HERE.
    endif ()
    # Do something to c...
endmacro()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros in CMake are basically substitutions, so you don't actually return from it. I'd suggest you wrapping "b" and "c" code into `else()`:

```
macro (my_macro a b c)
    if (NOT USE_${a})
         # I WANT TO RETURN FROM HERE.
    else ()
    if (NOT USE_${b})
         # I WANT TO RETURN FROM HERE.
    endif ()
    # Do something to c...
    endif(NOT USE_${a})
endmacro()
```