# Return in CMake macro ends upper CMake file execution?

Tags: cmake

I have added `return()` in a middle of CMake's macro.

But suspect that it had like exit behavior for CMake script, so CMake execution would not continue any further. Is that really true, and is it a bug or feature?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307515/cmake-macro-return-from-middle-of-the-flow.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`return`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html):

> Note that a macro, unlike a function, is expanded in place and therefore cannot handle return().

In other words, your macro is placed within the CMake file from which it was called. So by calling `return()`, you are returning from *that* CMake file. If you want to return from your macro, without exiting the containing CMake file as well, I suggest replacing `macro` with CMake's [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html).

If interested, a complete list of differences between `macro` and `function` is documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html#macro-vs-function).

---

There is no equivalent for `exit()` in CMake, to terminate CMake processing altogether from some arbitrary point in the CMake code. However, you can force CMake to terminate by throwing an error with a [`message`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html):

```
message(FATAL_ERROR "Exiting...")
```